# How to use a searchbar in application?

Tags: iphone

i am new in iphone application Development and i want to put search bar in my application so please give me some suggestion how to implement search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend checking out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).  If you need to see samples, Apple has a great collection including the [TableSearch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007848) and the [UICatalog](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710).  After going through these documents, please feel free to ask any followup questions and you'll definitely get some more specific help.